# Unormalize an normalized output

Tags: neural-network, normalization, keras

I am currently working with a NN problem, in which i am mapping an input to an output.

I've normalized the input and the output such that they are in the same range => -1 to 1 and such that i can use tanh as activation function.

I seem to get pretty decent result from the training, val_loss = 0.0156.

But to actually use the dataset I have to unormalize the output, which makes it very different from the actual output.

I am pretty new to NN , but is unormalizing usually done?? if not? how are these issues then resolved?

I am currently normalizing using min-max nomalization, and since i store the max and min value, I use those to return the values.

**More about the data:**

The dataset consist of [stft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) audio files, and the output is a feature vector ([mfcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)). 
Since stft is giving me complex values, but since keras isn't able to handle complex numbers, I've splitted the real and imaginary part, and concantenated them.

Comment: can u please explain what is the output? is it binary classification problem? the normalization in input is usually done, but for the output it is not

Comment: I don't understand, you want to return to original values and have the min and max values used to normalize, so what is the problem?

Comment: I've added some info about the output..  
The problem here is that the error increases as I normalise it..

Comment: Is it somehow possible to incorporate the unormalize step in keras, such that what when it updates the weight, or computes the loss, it would be based on the unormalized output vs. the real output instead of it being comparing the normalized real output vs. normalized output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) to do the unormalization step as part of the network itself.

Lets say you can define a normalization function:

```
f = K.function(/* some function */)
```

And your current model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=1000))
model.add(Dense(1000))
```

You can normalize the outputs by doing:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=1000))
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: f(x))
```

Comment: basically i want to apply a function on a numpy.ndarray. I guess you are right about the use of the lambda layer... There doesn't seem to be much information about how to use it.. Is there a simple way to use it?